# Resize Wry WebView from window.resizeTo

Tags: rust, tauri

I have a web application currently running in Electron and would like to move it to Wry/Tauri for opening speed.
The application uses `window.resizeTo` to change the window size in real time.
I have tried using the same command with Wry/Tauri, but it does not work.
Is it possible to intercept such a call and act correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe will be useful for someone other. I figured out that it is possible to use `webview.evaluate_script('<js code>')` to inject some code in opened page.
Thus it's possible to change the default `window.resizeTo` functionallity to something I need to, for example for my needs I can do:

```
window.resizeTo = (w, h) => window.ipc.postMessage(`resize,${w},${h}`);
```

On the `WRY` side I can use `with_ipc_handler` to resize the window as requested.

```
WebViewBuilder::new()
  .with_ipc_handler(|win, msg| {
    let (w, h) = parse_resize_msg(&msg).unwrap();
    win.set_inner_size(LogicalSize::new(w, h)).unwrap();
  })
  .build()?;
```